# Communicate between two different HTML files on different devices (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

I want to communicate between two different HTML files. One is opened on my iPad (iPad.html) and the other one on my pc (pc.html). When I press a button on the iPad.html I want to execute a function on the pc.html.

Is this possible with HTML and Javscript only? There would be a solution with PHP but I want to keep it "simple".

Answer (score 1):

one solution to achive this is by using websockets. Which holds a continuous connection with the server.

The flow will be like this.

- ipad.html and pc.html will open the websocket connection with the 
  php server.
- When you tap on ipad.html file it emits the event to the socket.
- From your php sever you emit a event to pc.html file to achieve this.

Please take a look on this php websockets library http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Since you are using only html there should be an broker to pass information from one client to another. So you have program some server side code otherwise it is difficult to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, because they don't know each other, yet. You can change that if you modify one of the clients to interact as a server, but if you say that you only want to use Javascript, take a look at [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), Node lets you build a server backend with pure javascript, then you can connect both clients to this node server and can communicate over that.